# Coudn't get result of highchart

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, codeigniter

I am using `highchart`, it gives result.

But, when I am going to make date range, nothing is happening and even my result goes blank!

I just want to find where I am wrong!

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        var options = { 
            chart: 
            {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'column',                                
                marginRight: 130,
                marginBottom: 25
            },
            rangeSelector: 
            {
                selected: 1,
                inputDateFormat: '%Y-%m-%d',
                inputEditDateFormat: '%Y-%m-%d'
            },
            title: 
            {
                text: 'Project Requests',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: 
            {
                text: '',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: 
            {
                categories: []
            },
            yAxis: 
            {
                title: 
                {
                    text: 'Requests'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: 
            {
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+this.x +': '+ this.y;
                }
            },
            legend: 
            {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: -10,
                y: 100,
                borderWidth: 0
            },                      
            series: []
        }

        $.getJSON("data", function(json) 
        {
            options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
            options.series[0] = json[1];
            options.series[1] = json[2];
            // options.series[2] = json[3];
            chart = new Highcharts.StockCart(options);
        });

        function (chart) 
        {
            setTimeout(function () 
            {
                $('input.highcharts-range-selector', $(chart.container).parent())
                .datepicker({
                    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
                    todayBtn: "linked",
                    orientation: "auto left",
                    autoclose: true,
                    todayHighlight: true
                });
            }, 0);

            $.datepicker.setDefaults
            ({
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                onSelect: function (dateText) {
                    this.onchange();
                    this.onblur();
                }
            });
</script>
```

Here my Controller:

```
<?php

if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Chart extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('Data');
        $this->load->helper('url');

    }

    public function index()
    {
        //echo "adsf";exit;
        $this->load->view('allindex');
    }

    public function data()
    {

            $data = $this->Data->get_data();

            $category = array();
            $category['name'] = 'date';

            $series1 = array();
            $series1['name'] = 'employee_id';

            $series2 = array();
            $series2['name'] = 'customer_id';

//            $series3 = array();
//            $series3['name'] = 'sale_id';

            foreach ($data as $row)
            {
                $category['data'][] = $row->date;
                $series1['data'][] = $row->employee_id;
                $series2['data'][] = $row->customer_id;
//                $series3['data'][] = $row->sale_id;
            }

            $result = array();
            array_push($result,$category);
            array_push($result,$series1);
            array_push($result,$series2);
//            array_push($result,$series3);

            print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
    }
```

Here is Model:

```
 <?php
class Data extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function get_data()
    {
        $this->db->select('date,sale_id,employee_id,customer_id');
        $this->db->from('ospos_sales');
        $this->db->where("`date` BETWEEN '2013-10-11' AND '2013-10-12'");
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();

    }

}
```

Comment: can you make it on jsfiddle ??

Comment: Does your HTML have the containing div for highcharts to render to?  It's not shown in the code.  Also, can you add in the data you are looking to plot, as there might be an issue with that?

Comment: You can see my above code.. @sorav and gabe3886

Comment: Fragment revised to make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

The only idea that there is a problem with dateFormat. Try to comment this lines

```
inputDateFormat: '%Y-%m-%d',
inputEditDateFormat: '%Y-%m-%d'
```

i have no more idea